Packer for Windows machine - how can I set the user name used for building?
I am trying to build a windows machine in azure using packing. Unfortunately one flaky piece of software needs a specific user name (Think Something Like StoreID_1234) so it can be installed. How can I tell Packer to use that user name?
Current packer file:
packer {
  required_plugins {
    azure = {
      source  = "github.com/hashicorp/azure"
      version = "~> 2"
    }
  }
}

source "azure-arm" "avd" {
  # WinRM Communicator

  communicator   = "winrm"
  winrm_use_ssl  = true
  winrm_insecure = true
  winrm_timeout  = "5m"
  winrm_username = "packer"

  # Service Principal Authentication

  # subscription_id = var.subscription_id
  # tenant_id       = var.tenant_id

  use_azure_cli_auth = true

  # Source Image

  os_type         = "Windows"
  image_publisher = var.source_image_publisher
  image_offer     = var.source_image_offer
  image_sku       = var.source_image_sku
  image_version   = var.source_image_version

  # Destination Image

  managed_image_resource_group_name = var.artifacts_resource_group
  managed_image_name                = "${var.source_image_sku}-${var.source_image_version}"

  # Packer Computing Resources

  build_resource_group_name = var.build_resource_group
  vm_size                   = "Standard_DS3_v2"

}

build {
  source "azure-arm.avd" {}

  # Install Chocolatey: https://chocolatey.org/install#individual
  provisioner "powershell" {
    inline = ["Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://community.chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))"]
  }

  # Install Chocolatey packages
  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "./packages.config"
    destination = "D:/packages.config"
  }

  provisioner "powershell" {
    inline = ["choco install --confirm D:/packages.config"]
    # See https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/choco/commands/install#exit-codes
    valid_exit_codes = [0, 3010]
  }

  provisioner "windows-restart" {}

  # Azure PowerShell Modules
  provisioner "powershell" {
    script = "./install-azure-powershell.ps1"
  }

  # Generalize image using Sysprep
  # See https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/azure/arm#windows
  # See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/build-image-with-packer#define-packer-template
  provisioner "powershell" {
    inline = [
      "while ((Get-Service RdAgent).Status -ne 'Running') { Start-Sleep -s 5 }",
      "while ((Get-Service WindowsAzureGuestAgent).Status -ne 'Running') { Start-Sleep -s 5 }",
      "& $env:SystemRoot\\System32\\Sysprep\\Sysprep.exe /oobe /generalize /quiet /quit /mode:vm",
      "while ($true) { $imageState = Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Setup\\State | Select ImageState; if($imageState.ImageState -ne 'IMAGE_STATE_GENERALIZE_RESEAL_TO_OOBE') { Write-Output $imageState.ImageState; Start-Sleep -s 10  } else { break } }"
    ]
  }
}



The Powershell process would need to execute as that user, and so this question should probably be redone as a PS question. Packer generally connects as the Azure cloud-init user during the AzureRM build.
